# What is the official method for setting a static node with geth v1.6.0?

Tags: go-ethereum

I've tried placing a `static-nodes.json` file in the data directory and I've tried specifying the static node in a TOML file.  Neither approach seemed to have the desired effect.

Comment: Hi there, Max. Can you clarify what desired effect you're expecting?

Comment: Hi Richard.  I was attempting to sync to a private chain.  I expected block sync to commence, as it always did with previous versions of geth for this particular network, but it never does.  I use a `<datadir>/static-nodes.json` file for this private chain.  Endpoints successfully open and the RLPx listener starts, but `net.peerCount` returns zero.  It should always return at least "1".  To be candid, the static node could be a red herring and 1.6 might have a problem with my genesis file, as I understand that its format has changed?

`invalid genesis file: hex string has odd length`

Comment: Aha, yes, it could be the genesis file issue. Does this answer help? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15314/52

Comment: Thanks again Richard.  I saw that.  I understood it to mean that as of v1.6, genesis json property values must be expressed in decimal, not hex?  I changed hex properties to decimal and noticed that geth was indeed able to write the genesis block.  After that, still no block sync.  

I'm wondering if through conversion of the genesis file, I might have changed it such that I'm no longer able to connect to the same network?  And therefore, the `<datadir>/static-nodes.json` concern might be a red herring?  Not sure of that either.  Is `<datadir>/static-nodes.json` no longer supported?

Comment: I hadn't heard anything about `static-nodes.json` not being supported anymore. To be safe, you could try adding the nodes using `--bootnodes`: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2709/52. If that works, then it might rule out the problem with the genesis file.

Comment: Be careful, the correct path is <datadir>/geth/static-nodes.json according to https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#static-nodes. I've placed a symbolic link to cover both bases.